# How to index JSON data in PostgreSQL 9.2?

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.2

Does anyone know how to create index on JSON data in PostgreSQL 9.2?

Example data:

```
[
  {"key" : "k1", "value" : "v1"},
  {"key" : "k2", "value" : "v2"}
]
```

Say if I want to index on all the keys how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're storing plain JSON and not separating into table columns? And any reason you don't accept answers?

Comment: I am evaluating the JSON type support PostgreSQL 9.2 and hence the need. I don't see a setting that disables receiving answers? Is there something like that?

Comment: Maybe take a look at: http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/249-Using-PLV8-to-index-JSON.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are much better off using hstore for indexed fields, at least for now.

```
CREATE INDEX table_name_gin_data ON table_name USING GIN(data);
```

You can also create GIST indexes if you are interested in fulltext search. More info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-indexes.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no built-in functions to index JSON directly. But you can do it with a function based index where the function is written in JavaScript.

See this blog post for details: http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/249-Using-PLV8-to-index-JSON.html

There is another blog post from which talks about JSON and how it can be used with JavaScript: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/272-Using-PLV8-to-build-JSON-selectors.html

Comment: But in my case - I need to index everything in the json object. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @ankurvsoni: no, I don't think so.

Comment: Note that since 9.3 there are [JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old but I think the selected answer is not really the ideal one. To index json (the property values inside json text), we can use expression indexes with PLV8 (suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name).

Craig Kerstein does a great job of explaining/demonstrating:

http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/05/29/postgres-indexes-expression-or-functional-indexes/